# ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) on python3.10

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I Updated my python3 version to 3.10 now my sticky note giving this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/indicator-stickynotes", line 21, in <module>
    from stickynotes.gui import *
  File "/usr/share/indicator-stickynotes/stickynotes/gui.py", line 20, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I update my python from 3.8 to 3.9.5 and had the same issue. This was because python 3.10 is updated but the filename of the .so file of the package is not changed. So the `__init__.py` of the gi package will try to load a file whose name contains the previous version of python.

One solution would be make a copy of the .so file and rename it.

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/
sudo cp _gi.cpython-{older version number}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Please replace the {older version number} to a older python version so that the file of this name exists in the directory.